# Зачем нужны переменные таблицы и когда их лучше использовать?

Tags: sql, sql-server

В MS SQL есть переменные таблицы.

В некоторых случаях я замечал, что темповые таблицы работают быстрее, за счет того, что в них используется параллелизм в отличии от переменных.

Единственный минус темповых таблиц, как я думаю - это то, что их нужно проверять и дропать если они есть перед создание.

Так вот, для каких целей они могут понадобится, когда есть темповые таблицы и когда их лучше использовать?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Единственный минус темповых таблиц, как я думаю - это то, что их нужно
>   проверять и дропать если они есть перед созданием.

На мой взгляд это проблема только при `@@nestlevel` равном 0, да и то не всегда (например, если открываем соединение, создаём `#`-таблицу, что-то делаем и закрываем соединение, то в проверке нет необходимости). Внутри модуля (триггера или процедуры), если нужно создать `#table`, то можно не проверять и не дропать (это может быть и вредным), даже если на внешнем уровне уже была создана `#table` с тем же самым именем.

Т.е., например, есть процедура

```
create procedure SomeProc
as
begin
    set nocount on;

    create table #table (id int);
    insert into #table values (1), (2);

    select * from #table;
end
GO
```

Можно создать `#table` и вызвать `SomeProc`

```
create table #table (value float);
insert into #table values (100.0), (200.0);
exec SomeProc; -- #table внутри SomeProc - это другая #table
select * from #table;
drop table #table;
GO
```

при этом `#table`, созданная снаружи `SomeProc`, и `#table`, созданная внутри `SomeProc` - разные и между собой не интерферируют. Если внутри `SomeProc` перед `create table #table` поставить проверку существования `#table` и `drop table #table`, то уничтожится таблица, созданная на внешнем уровне, и код, следующий за процедурой, сломается.

> Так вот, для каких целей они могут понадобиться, когда есть темповые
>   таблицы

При выборе между `@table` и `#table`, как мне кажется, следует исходить из свойств и особенностей этих двух типов таблиц. У `@`-таблиц по сравнению с `#`-таблицами довольно много ограничений, много общего, и есть особенности присущие только `@`-таблицам.

Подробно этот вопрос освещён [здесь](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13777841) и [здесь](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/16386). Ниже некоторое обобщение информации по этим двум ссылкам (неполное).

---

**Хранилище:** Вопреки расхожему представлению о том, что `@`-таблицы хранятся в оперативной памяти, а `#`-таблицы - в *tempdb*, разницы в этом плане между ними на самом деле нет. И те и другие хранятся в *tempdb*, и, также, и те и другие одинаково буферизуются.

**Область видимости:** `#`-таблицы доступны на том уровне, на котором они создаются и на вложенных (`@@nestlevel` больше текущего). `@`-таблицы доступны только в рамках того batch-а или модуля, в котором они объявляются (впрочем, типированные `@`-таблицы на вложенные уровни можно передавать параметром).

**Жизненный цикл:** `@`-таблицы создаются неявно в самом начале того батча, в котором они объявлены, перед выполнением всех остальных команд (а если это модуль, то перед началом выполнения модуля), независимо от того, будет ли достигнута в процессе исполнения соответствующая `declare` инструкция, или нет. Вот такой код, например, вполне работает:

```
if 1 != 0
    declare @table1 table (id int);
else
    declare @table2 table (name varchar(20));

select * from @table1;
select * from @table2;
GO
```

уничтожаются `@`-таблицы после выхода из соответствующего батча или модуля, в котором они объявлены.

`#`-таблицы создаются тогда, когда встречается соответствующая `create table` инструкция; уничтожаются тогда, когда встречается соответствующая `drop table` инструкция, либо при уменьшении уровня вложенности (выхода из модуля или `exec` инструкции), или закрытии соединения (если `#`-таблица была создана на нулевом уровне вложенности).

**Использование в функциях и процедурах:** `#`-таблицы нельзя создавать в пользовательских скалярных и multi-line табличных функциях, `@`-таблицы - можно. Типированные `@`-таблицы можно передавать в функции и процедуры параметром. `#`-таблицы нельзя передавать в функции (хотя можно получить к ним доступ косвенно - через синоним). В процедурах `#`-таблицы, созданные на внешнем уровне - доступны.

**Сollation:** При создании `@`-таблиц столбцы строковых типов (если они присутствуют) наследуют *collation* от текущей БД. При создании `#`-таблиц столбцы строковых типов наследуют *collation* от *tempdb*, либо от текущей БД, если та является автономной (*contained*).

**Индексы/ключи:** До SqlServer 2014 на `@`-таблицах можно было задавать только уникальные ключи

```
declare @table table
(
    id int primary key,
    uid uniqueidentifier unique
)
```

В SqlServer 2014 с добавлением inline-синтаксиса для создания индексов стало возможным добавлять неуникальные индексы

```
declare @table table
(
    value varchar(20),
    index ix_1 (value)
)
```

В SqlServer 2016 стало возможным добавление уникальных и отфильтрованных индексов

```
declare @table table
(
    id int,
    value varchar(20),
    index ix_1 unique (value),
    index ix_2 (id) where value is NULL
)
```

Индексы с `include`, а также специальные виды индексов на `@`-таблицах на настоящий момент не поддерживаются.

**Компиляция запросов:** Оптимизатор запросов во многих случаях полагает, что `@`-таблица содержит одну единственную строку. На `@`-таблицах не поддерживаются статистики по столбцам.

**Транзакции:** Изменение содержимого `@`-таблиц всегда происходит в системной транзакции, поэтому они нечувствительны к `rollback`.

```
declare @table table (value int);
create table #table (value int);
begin tran;
insert into @table values (1);
insert into #table values (2);
rollback;
select * from @table;
select * from #table;
drop table #table;
```

**Параллелизм:** Запросы, меняющие содержимое `@table` (insert/update/delete) не могут использовать параллелизм. Запросы читающие из `@table` (select) могут иметь параллельный план.

**Табличные подсказки:** На `@`-таблицах нельзя использовать табличные подсказки (*table hints*), на `#`-таблицы такое ограничение не накладывается.

**Другое:** `@`-таблицу нельзя создать при помощи `select * into @table from ...`. Для `@`-таблиц недоступны `truncate table`, `alter table`, `create index`.

Answer (score 2):

1) Оптимизация

Переменные таблицы по возможности хранятся в ОЗУ, иначе в `tempdb`. На них, в отличие от временных, нельзя навешать гору индексов, триггеров итп.
Когда есть небольшой набор данных, который в скрипте несколько раз переиспользуется - временная таблица будет быстрее, чем обращение к `tempdb`.

2) Применимость

В отличие от временных таблиц, переменные таблицы можно создавать в пользовательских функциях.

**upd**
3) Конечно же область видимости.

Временные таблицы видны по имени во всём стеке вызовов хранимых процедур.
Локальные переменные таблицы только в пределах блока кода.

4+) Просто для информации.
Если создать временную таблицу с двумя решётками, то она будет доступна, пока жива хоть одна сессия, которая к ней обращалась.

```
CREATE TABLE ##TempTable ( ...
```

Иногда полезно, например для отчетов, которые требуют предрасчитанных данных за ночь = первый раз отчёт будет формироваться "долго" - все последующие быстрее, пока пересекаются сессии, которые этот запрос запускают.